# td widths are not applied on auto width table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LHsLM/1/.

I am trying to apply height and width to a auto width table using inline css as in the fiddle. But the styles are not applied.

html:

```
 <div id="a"></div>
```

css:

```
div {
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

js:

```
var str = ["<table>"];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";
  for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    tr += "<td style='width:120px;height:40px'>" + j + "</td>";   
  }
  tr+="</tr>";
  str.push(tr);
}
str.push("</table>");

document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = str.join('');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `width` to `min-width` of your td elements.

Sorry, that is not IE-8 compatible.

This method works for IE8 too:

```
function tablo(){
var str = ["<table>"];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        tr += "<td><div style='width:120px;height:40px'>" + j + "</div></td>";   
    }
    tr+="</tr>";
    str.push(tr);
}
str.push("</table>");
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = str.join('');
}
```

Comment: I've checked it in IE8 now, and I see min-width doesn't work for IE8.

Comment: Now found another solution which is IE8 compatible. See my updated post please.

Comment: I thank you because of you've warned me about IE8 compatibility. I didn't notice it at first :)